# Best way to read the JSON and INSERT INTO mysql using node.js programmatically

Tags: mysql, json, migration

Suggest a best way to read the json and insert it into mysql db.

Example JSON:

```
{
    "PaymentOrder": [
        {
            "$": {
                "Id": "83C44C4A-7EFD-491E-913E-007A3598618F",
                "Name": "",
                "OrderNumber": "AH9NZPUI",
                "OrderType": "Recurring",
                "Amount": "1.000000",
                "CouponDiscountAmount": ".000000",
                "ChargeAmount": ".000000",
                "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                "OwnerId": "D9F48450-AB86-4ABE-B9AD-66FE3B7AEFB1",
                "OrderStatus": "Pending",
                "PaymentProcessor": "Global Collect",
                "PaymentMethodType": "Visa",
                "SoftDescriptorText": "CNext_AH9NZPUI",
                "UserPaymentInfoId": "FDD9C487-6F66-4919-B945-766699C9EF1D",
                "IsAuthorization": "1",
                "CreateTime": "2012-07-18T10:21:47.7610377",
                "UpdateTime": "2012-07-18T10:21:47.7610377",
                "IsEnabled": "1",
                "IsDeleted": "0"
            }
        },
        {
            "$": {
                "Id": "03B1600F-F92A-47BA-8B53-00B70A942E43",
                "Name": "",
                "OrderNumber": "3427BBC3",
                "OrderType": "Recurring",
                "Amount": ".000000",
                "CouponDiscountAmount": ".000000",
                "ChargeAmount": ".000000",
                "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                "OwnerId": "9A1186E4-BAC6-43D0-8C6F-B02ECD6544B5",
                "OrderStatus": "Success",
                "PaymentProcessor": "Global Collect",
                "PaymentMethodType": "Visa",
                "SoftDescriptorText": "ComputeNext Inc Order Number - 3427BBC3",
                "UserPaymentInfoId": "142C6B38-A470-40A9-B7A7-1C8CDD6FBD2C",
                "BillingHistoryId": "6BE8DF8E-4C97-492B-9407-38EBA2B942F2",
                "InvoiceDate": "2013-03-26T14:02:07.8570464",
                "IsAuthorization": "0",
                "CreateTime": "2013-03-26T18:08:19.5383118",
                "UpdateTime": "2013-03-26T18:08:19.5695118",
                "IsEnabled": "1",
                "IsDeleted": "0"
            }
        },
        {
            "$": {
                "Id": "8FC1D8EA-C388-4F31-91C7-00CB54C337A4",
                "Name": "",
                "OrderNumber": "YTM8TOKQ",
                "OrderType": "Recurring",
                "Amount": "1.000000",
                "CouponDiscountAmount": ".000000",
                "ChargeAmount": ".000000",
                "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                "OwnerId": "3702AB47-1095-4211-B844-82C47D0D9F6C",
                "OrderStatus": "Failure",
                "PaymentProcessor": "Global Collect",
                "PaymentMethodType": "Visa",
                "SoftDescriptorText": "CNext_YTM8TOKQ",
                "UserPaymentInfoId": "19193F72-14D1-4A72-9676-2493002711ED",
                "TransactionDuration": "0:0:40:809",
                "LastTransactionNumber": "HC0F4CBYMT14QP3",
                "IsAuthorization": "1",
                "CreateTime": "2012-07-26T21:15:25.8004068",
                "UpdateTime": "2012-07-26T21:16:06.6100785",
                "IsEnabled": "1",
                "IsDeleted": "0"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The attributes present in JSON is equivalent to columns in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

You can code this in the language of your choice of course (you just need a JSON reading facility and a MySQL client but these are readily available in all languages these days) or you could use an ETL tool.

#### Advantage of using ETL

Changes to source or destination formats (eg all of a sudden you need to read these data from a CSV file or an XML file) or content (fields are added, or disappear, or are renamed) can typically be resolved by reconfiguring the tool.

#### Disadvantage of using ETL

It's yet another (rather heavy) piece of infrastructure you'll have to manage, and some will argue that using an ETL tool for such a task is like killing a fly with a sledgehammer.

Nevertheless, depending on your requirements regarding flexibility ETL could be the best/easiest solution.